# Manage quality and size of an UIImage with alpha channel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uigraphicscontext

I have an UIView with UIImageViews and UILabels, which I have to capture into image and then export to photo gallery. The image has a fixed size in pixels and must have alpha channel, because UIView background color is clear.

Now I use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions with renderInContext or drawViewHierarchyInRect, then I resize image to a given size and save it with UIImagePNGRepresentation. It works - I get an UIImage of the exact pixel size I need, with alpha channel, saved in gallery.

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_templateView.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
    [_templateView drawViewHierarchyInRect:_templateView.bounds afterScreenUpdates:NO];
    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(1080.0f, 1080.0f));
    [img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1080.0f, 1080.0f)];
    img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    NSData *pngImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
```

The problem is the size of the result image. It is a way larger than expected. When I add only one UIImageView (filling parent UIView) with the image of 1.2Mb. it's capture results in 1.65Mb.. It is crucial because I have a limit size for an image. How can I reduce it's size? Is is possible to reduce quality of such an image with alpha channel?

I tried resize it to 50% and then again to 100% but it results even in largest size.

Comment: So your goal is to persist image size and reduce file size at the expense of image quality? And it is crucial that the output image includes alpha component which makes JPEG useless?

Comment: @matic-oblak yes, exactly. Image size and alpha channel are constants. I know that PNG is lossless format, but I am looking for some workaround like downgrading RGB bits scheme or some manipulations with PNG which can reduce it's quality (unique colors).